# jquery toggle between password and text field IE bug

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, input, toggle

I am using this jquery from the link below for login toggle between password and text field

http://www.electrictoolbox.com/jquery-toggle-between-password-text-field/

I am testing on IE and basically when you toggle the password field (the username is fine), the input field goes smaller on focus, which really annoys me and spent last hour trying to figure it out, but couldn't so would like to ask for help if you can help me please

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Maybe a better solution is to use an [iPhone-like password field](http://blog.decaf.de/2009/07/iphone-like-password-fields-using-jquery/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in looking at that example it looks like it's switching between showing and hiding the following password fields:

```
<input id="password-clear" type="text" value="Password" autocomplete="off" />
<input id="password-password" type="password" name="password" value="" autocomplete="off" />
```

I'm thinking that the height and width of the 2 inputs (password-clear and password-password) are different in your code, hence when you show one it is a different size.  Make sure the CSS you are applying to both inputs is identical.

***Update***:
It seems IE is rendering some space from the input that's being hidden (pushing the other fields down).  I fixed it in this fiddle by making both the password fields absolutely positioned and adding some separational divs.
http://jsfiddle.net/LqXnx/5/

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Here is the fiddle 
http://jsfiddle.net/LqXnx/ i am using,
You an try on IE9 to see what I am talking about,

Thanks

Comment: Looks like IE9 is still rendering something of the old password field to be displayed for some reason.  You can set them to position:absolute to get rid of this rendered space (see update)

Comment: hey Brian, thanks a lot for this, it makes sense now, really appreciate it, cheers

Comment: Sure thing :) Since this answer helped you out can you mark it as the accepted answer by pressing the checkbox next to it? Thanks!